# INSERT INTO based on value in cell

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `foo` like this

*foo*

```
id   fruit    origin
1    avocado  NULL
2    orange   NULL
3    apple    NULL
```

I want to `insert`, based on a `where` clause
Something like

```
INSERT INTO foo (origin) VALUES (`australia`) WHERE fruit = `avocado`;
```

But that does not work? How do I insert, based on a value in a cell?

Comment: There is no WHERE condition in an INSERT. Looks like you want to UPDATE that record. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an *update* here, not an insert:

```sql
UPDATE foo
SET origin = 'Australia'
WHERE fruit = 'avocado';
```